# Proof of commutator in Tong's notes on QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, dirac-delta-distributions

I am following David Tong's notes on QFT: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html . In equation 2.21, he tries to prove $$[\phi(\vec{x}),\pi(\vec{y})] = i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y}).$$ Here, $\phi$ and $\pi$ are the quantum field and its momentum conjugate respectively. $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are two points in space.

I have understood the first part of the proof but can someone help me with how to transition between the two lines below:

$$[\phi(\vec{x}),\pi(\vec{y})] = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{(-i)}{2}(-e^{i\vec{p}.(\vec{x}-\vec{y})}-e^{i\vec{p}.(\vec{y}-\vec{x})})$$
$$[\phi(\vec{x}),\pi(\vec{y})] = i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$$

Comment: Do you know the Fourier integral representation of the Dirac delta distribution?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of it. I found the integral representation of the one dimensional Dirac delta distribution and guessed the three dimensional version. I think I can work it now.

Comment: You can post this as an answer to avoid this showing up in the unanswered questions pile.